# Is there an uncountable set S, a subset of P(N), such that for any A,B an element of S; the intersection of A and B is finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a feeling no such uncountable set exists but have no idea how I could formulate a proof to show this. If such an uncountable set did exist I could try and use a form of the diagonalization method to show this, but haven't been able to find one so far... If someone could just start me off and give me an idea where to go with this question that would be great.

Comment: What's T? You should write the text of your problem clearly

Comment: Ah sorry T should be S...

Comment: For each irrational, choose a sequence of rationals that converge to it. Then, "transfer" to $\cal P(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: What do you mean transfer? Form a bijection? Sorry, I don't really understand the significance of considering the irrationals.

Comment: David is saying: the irrationals are uncountable, and there's a way to associate to each irrational an element of $P(\mathbb{N})$, such that the intersections are finite

Comment: The set of all finite sets is countable. (Oh, the other comment has been deleted.)

Comment: The point is (and is not my idea), finding such a family of sets is relatively easy to do in $\Bbb R$. Given two distinct irrationals, the corresponding sequences can have at most finitely many terms in common.

Comment: Thanks David, I think I can see what to do now.

Comment: Identify (find a bijection) the set of rationals and $\Bbb N$. Use that to do the "transfer".

Answer (score 2):

For every real $\alpha\in [0,1)$ with $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ the digits of $\alpha$, let $A_{\alpha}=\{1,1a_1, 1a_1a_2, 1a_1a_2a_3, \ldots\}\in P(\mathbb{N})$. For $\beta\neq \alpha$, the sets $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ will not agree after some finite number of elements in the sequence because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ stop agreeing after some finite number of digits. Let $S=\{A_{\alpha}\}\subset P(\mathbb{N})$ and we are done.

Comment: You might want $\alpha\in[0.1,1)$, otherwise $\alpha$ and $\alpha/10$ will produce the same set (with zero added if it's not in $A_\alpha$).

Comment: @Heimdall thanks. Easier to fix imo by just prefixing by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, from David Mitra's comment:

f is a bijection from rationals to naturals.

For each irrational number $a$ choose one of rational sequences converging to it, $\{x_n\}$ and define the set $A_a=\{f(x_n):n\in N\}$. Then

$$S=\{A_a:a\in R\setminus Q\}$$

As pointed out earlier, any two sequences and therefore any two sets $A_a$ and $A_b$ will only agree in finite elements.

Of course, this solution depends on the Axiom of Choice, whereas Daniel's doesn't.